# Unable to upload file with form data from angular to sails.js using ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, sails.js, ng2-file-upload

My app.component.html contains

`<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" #photoupload="ngModel" required id="photoupload" name="photo_upload" [(ngModel)]="personal.photo">`

app.component.ts contains

```
this.uploader = new FileUploader({ url: "http://localhost:1337/api/fmng/create" });
this.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item) => {
    var formData = [{ "formdata" : this.personal }];
    item.formData.push({ fileData: formData });

};
```

Code in my controller of the sails app is

```
req.file('photo_upload').upload({ dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images') }, function (err, uploadedFiles) {
     if (err) return res.serverError(err);
     console.log('req all params ' + req.allParams());
}
```

Why there is no request being made on the URL from my angular app?